# How can I fix bugs in Custom Repository?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to make a Custom Repository with spring-data-jpa.

### My codes

#### Repository

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
interface CustomRepository<T, ID : Serializable> : JpaRepository<T, ID> {
    fun findBySomeRestrict(id: ID): T?
}
```

#### RepositoryImpl

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class CustomRepositoryImpl<T, ID : Serializable>(
    private val entityManager: EntityManager,
    jpaEntityInformation: JpaMetamodelEntityInformation<T, ID>
) : SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>(jpaEntityInformation, entityManager), CustomRepository<T, ID> {

    override fun findBySomeRestrict(id: ID): T? {
        // TODO
    }

}
```

#### Main class

```java
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = CustomRepositoryImpl::class)
@SpringBootApplication
class ForSubmitApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<ForSubmitApplication>(*args)
}
```

### MyErrorMessage

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable constructor found on interface com.example.forsubmit.global.custom.CustomRepository to match the given arguments: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation, jdk.proxy2.$Proxy132. Make sure you implement a constructor taking these
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$instantiateClass$6(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.instantiateClass(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:542) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:182) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:164) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:75) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:324) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:322) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:328) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
```

#### What I do to fix it

- Change the type of constructor to `JpaEntityInformation`
- Decompile the code

Comment: Please read the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Comment: I alreay tried all of them!
But I can't fix my bug

Answer (score 0):

It seems you only want to provide the implementation of one method.
In that case you must not set `repositoryBaseClass`.

Instead you want to [follow the steps outlined in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior).

1. Create an interface just containing the custom method(s). You currently don't have that.
2. Create an implementation of it. You are currently implementing the final Repository interface which is wrong.
3. Extend your final repository interface from the custom interface created in step 1.

Comment: Thank you for answering!